# Need help implementing a Lucas Pseudoprimality test

Tags: primes

I am trying to write a function that determines if a number *n* is prime or composite using the Lucas pseudoprime test; at the moment, I am working with the standard test, but once I get that working I will then write the strong test. I am reading the [paper](http://mpqs.free.fr/LucasPseudoprimes.pdf) by Baillie and Wagstaff, and following the [implementation](http://www.trnicely.net/misc/bpsw.html) by Thomas Nicely in the [trn.c](http://www.trnicely.net/misc/trn.zip) file.

I understand that the full test involves several steps: trial division by small primes, checking that *n* is not a square, performing a strong pseudoprimality test to base 2, then finally the Lucas pseudoprime test. I can handle all the other pieces, but I am having trouble with the Lucas pseudoprime test. Here is my implementation, in Python:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def jacobi(a, m):
    a = a % m; t = 1
    while a != 0:
        while a % 2 == 0:
            a = a / 2
            if m % 8 == 3 or m % 8 == 5:
                t = -1 * t
        a, m = m, a # swap a and m
        if a % 4 == 3 and m % 4 == 3:
            t = -1 * t
        a = a % m
    if m == 1:
        return t
    return 0

def isLucasPrime(n):
    dAbs, sign, d = 5, 1, 5
    while 1:
        if 1 < gcd(d, n) > n:
            return False
        if jacobi(d, n) == -1:
            break
        dAbs, sign = dAbs + 2, sign * -1
        d = dAbs * sign
    p, q = 1, (1 - d) / 4
    print "p, q, d =", p, q, d
    u, v, u2, v2, q, q2 = 0, 2, 1, p, q, 2 * q
    bits = []
    t = (n + 1) / 2
    while t > 0:
        bits.append(t % 2)
        t = t // 2
    h = -1
    while -1 * len(bits) <= h:
        print "u, u2, v, v2, q, q2, bits, bits[h] = ",\
               u, u2, v, v2, q, q2, bits, bits[h]
        u2 = (u2 * v2) % n
        v2 = (v2 * v2 - q2) % n
        if bits[h] == 1:
            u = u2 * v + u * v2
            u = u if u % 2 == 0 else u + n
            u = (u / 2) % n
            v = (v2 * v) + (u2 * u * d)
            v = v if v % 2 == 0 else v + n
            v = (v / 2) % n
        if -1 * len(bits) < h:
            q = (q * q) % n
            q2 = q + q
        h = h - 1
    return u == 0
```

When I run this, `isLucasPrime` returns `False` for such primes as 83 and 89, which is incorrect. It also returns `False` for the composite 111, which is correct. And it returns `False` for the composite 323, which I know is a Lucas pseudoprime for which `isLucasPrime` should return `True`. In fact, `isLucasPseudoprime` returns `False` for every *n* on which I have tested it.

I have several questions:

1) I'm not expert with C/GMP, but it seems to me that Nicely runs through the bits of `(n+1)/2` from right-to-left (least significant to most significant) where other authors run through the bits left-to-right. My code shown above runs through the bits left-to-right, but I have also tried running through the bits right-to-left, with the same result. Which order is correct?

2) It looks odd to me that Nicely only updates the *u* and *v* variables for a 1-bit. Is this correct? I expected to update all four of the Lucas-chain variables each time through the loop, since the indexes of the chain increase at each step.

3) What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) I'm not expert with C/GMP, but it seems to me that Nicely runs through the bits of `(n+1)/2` from right-to-left (least significant to most significant) where other authors run through the bits left-to-right. My code shown above runs through the bits left-to-right, but I have also tried running through the bits right-to-left, with the same result. Which order is correct?

Indeed, Nicely goes from least significant to most significant bit. He computes `U(2^k)` and `V(2^k)` (and `Q^(2^k)`; all modulo `N` of course), in the `mpzU2m` and `mpzV2m` variables, and has `U((N+1) % 2^k)` resp `V((N+1) % 2^k)` stored in `mpzU` and `mpzV`. When a 1-bit is encountered, the remainder `(N+1) % 2^k` changes, and `mpzU` and `mpzV` are updated accordingly.

The other way is to compute `U(p)`, `U(p+1)`, `V(p)` and (optionally) `V(p+1)` for a prefix `p` of `N+1` and combine those to compute `U(2*p+1)` and either `U(2*p)` or `U(2*p+2)` [ditto for `V`] depending on whether the next bit after the prefix `p` is 0 or 1.

Both methods are correct, like you can compute the power `x^N` going from left to right, having `x^p` and `x^(p+1)` as state, or from right to left having `x^(2^k)` and `x^(N % 2^k)` as state [and, computing `U(n)` and `U(n+1)` is basically computing `ζ^n` where `ζ = (1 + sqrt(D))/2`].

I - and others, apparently - find the left-to-right order simpler. I haven't done or read an analysis, it might be that right-to-left is computationally less expensive on average and Nicely chose right-to-left because of that.

> 2) It looks odd to me that Nicely only updates the `u` and `v` variables for a 1-bit. Is this correct? I expected to update all four of the Lucas-chain variables each time through the loop, since the indexes of the chain increase at each step.

Yes, that is correct, because the remainder `(N+1) % 2^k == (N+1) % 2^(k-1)` if the `2^k` bit is 0.

> 3) What have I done wrong?

A small typo first:

```
if 1 < gcd(d, n) > n:
```

should be

```
if 1 < gcd(d, n) < n:
```

of course.

More substantially, you use the updates for Nicely's traversal order (right-to-left), but traverse in the other direction. That of course produces wrong results.

Further, when updating `v`

```
    if bits[h] == 1:
        u = u2 * v + u * v2
        u = u if u % 2 == 0 else u + n
        u = (u / 2) % n
        v = (v2 * v) + (u2 * u * d)
        v = v if v % 2 == 0 else v + n
        v = (v / 2) % n
```

you use the new value of `u`, but you ought to use the old value.

```
def isLucasPrime(n):
    dAbs, sign, d = 5, 1, 5
    while 1:
        if 1 < gcd(d, n) < n:
            return False
        if jacobi(d, n) == -1:
            break
        dAbs, sign = dAbs + 2, sign * -1
        d = dAbs * sign
    p, q = 1, (1 - d) // 4
    u, v, u2, v2, q, q2 = 0, 2, 1, p, q, 2 * q
    bits = []
    t = (n + 1) // 2
    while t > 0:
        bits.append(t % 2)
        t = t // 2
    h = 0
    while h < len(bits):
        u2 = (u2 * v2) % n
        v2 = (v2 * v2 - q2) % n
        if bits[h] == 1:
            uold = u
            u = u2 * v + u * v2
            u = u if u % 2 == 0 else u + n
            u = (u // 2) % n
            v = (v2 * v) + (u2 * uold * d)
            v = v if v % 2 == 0 else v + n
            v = (v // 2) % n
        if h < len(bits) - 1:
            q = (q * q) % n
            q2 = q + q
        h = h + 1
    return u == 0
```

works (no guarantees, but I think it is correct, and have done some tests, all of which it passed).